# How adding an Interface to a WCF ServiceContract changes the URL of the methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, interface

I am trying to fully understand how adding an Interface in WCF affects the URI of the methods.  I have a ServiceContract defined like this:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceContract]
public class DataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<List<string>> ListTestMethod()
    {
        return new List<List<string>> 
        { 
            new List<string> {"0", "Test String 1"},
            new List<string> {"1", "Test String 2"},
            new List<string> {"2", "Test String 3"}
        };

    }

}
```

In my web.config file I have the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="epBehavior" >
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="DataService"
               behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">

        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="epBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="DataService" />

      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I test the method via a browser:

```
http://localhost/DataService.svc/ListTestMethod
```

I get this which is the expected result:

```
[["0","Test String 1"],["1","Test String 2"],["2","Test String 3"]]
```

So now I would like to add an interface to the code behind with something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<List<string>> ListTestMethod();
}
```

And of course go back to the DataService class and add the appropriate ": IDataService" implementation while removing the adorners that are now already in the Interface. Here is where I have trouble as the URL above no longer works.

I tried updating web.confg to this (note changes to name and contract attributes):

```
<services>
  <service name="IDataService.DataService"
           behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior"> 

    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="epBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IDataService.DataService" />

  </service>
</services>
```

Which seems to get the service going again but I cant actually get to the methods and if I add enable serviceMetadata it can no longer get to the metadata (it can in the original version).  I have tried all kinds of combinations of the web.config and the URL but cannot seem to get my arms around it.  How do I wire in the new Interface appropriately?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to venerik I got it working but changing the endpoint to point at the interface but leaving the service as is:

```
<services>
  <service name="DataService"
           behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior"> 

    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="epBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IDataService.DataService" />

  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully confident of this answer but I think your web.config should point to the interface:

```
<endpoint
    ...
    contract="IDataService"/>
```

Your service host file should point to the concrete implementation:

```
<% @ServiceHost Language=C# Service="SomeNamespace.DataService" %>
```

Info about [@ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  You were dead on actually.  My mistake was I was changing the name attr in the service declaration to also point at the interface and THAT was wrong - it should have remained pointed at the class itself.  Which makes sense the interface defines the signaure (i.e. contract) while the class defines the implementation (the service itself).